# How to set a retry for a pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with a call to an Azure function in. In order to property wait for completion of the function and handle any errors, I have additional tasks that monitor the functions status.

If the Function fails, I would like it to retry, however no errors are raised from the Azure Function activity if a 500 is returned, this is handled in an additional activity.

I want to put a retry on the entire pipeline that handles the call, but there does not appear to be a retry property on a pipeline execution. How do I do this?

Edit:

This pipeline is run from inside another pipeline, but is missing the retry option that activity pipelines have
[image]

Comment: What if you use an Until and Wait activity to run again the pipeline. You can put a counter simulating `i++` with set variables then you can decide how many tries to stop the Until loop and continue with your desired process.

Answer (score 3):

As far as retries on entire pipelines go: this depends on the type of trigger you're using.

> The following table provides a comparison of the tumbling window trigger and schedule trigger:
>
> | Item | Tumbling window trigger | Schedule trigger |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... |  |  |
> | **Retry capability** | Supported. Failed pipeline runs have a default retry policy of 0, or a policy that's specified by the user in the trigger definition. Automatically retries when the pipeline runs fail due to concurrency/server/throttling limits (that is, status codes 400: User Error, 429: Too many requests, and 500: Internal Server error). | Not supported. |
> | ... |  |  |

Source: [Pipeline execution and triggers in Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics - Trigger type comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#trigger-type-comparison)

The other option is to have retry logic for *activities*:

> The **activities** section can have one or more activities defined within it. There are two main types of activities: Execution and Control Activities.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Activity policy
>
> Policies affect the run-time behavior of an activity, giving configuration options. Activity Policies are only available for execution activities.
>
> [...]
>
> | JSON name | Description | Allowed Values | Required |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | timeout | Specifies the timeout for the activity to run. | Timespan | No. Default timeout is 7 days. |
> | retry | Maximum retry attempts | Integer | No. Default is 0 |
> | retryIntervalInSeconds | The delay between retry attempts in seconds | Integer | No. Default is 30 seconds |
> | secureOutput | When set to true, the output from activity is considered as secure and aren't logged for monitoring. | Boolean | No. Default is false. |

Source: [Pipelines and activities in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities?tabs=data-factory#activity-policy-json-definition).

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear that I'm running this pipeline from inside another pipeline, it seems like activities can retry, but pipelines can not.

Comment: @Neil P, Can you please tell me how did you solved this problem?Im facing the same issue.

Comment: @Never_Give_Up Sadly, I'm still not aware of a way to do this.

Comment: @NeilP Have you tried implementing the tumbling window trigger?

Comment: @Never_Give_Up I'm not sure that helps when calling from another pipeline.

Comment: @NeilP I think it helps for sure and we can set up the cross dependency between pipeline. Why don't you raise a case with miscrosoft about this issue and see what they suggest?

Answer (score 0):

As @virtualdvid has said and I tested, you can encapsulate the whole pipeline or its activities with an `until` checking for success.

> @contains(activity(<name>).output,'500')

[Create an Until activity with UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-until-activity#create-an-until-activity-with-ui)

Comment: How can we do that?

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheus, just create a `until` activity and add the code I provided as a dynamic content